# Formula for total magnification of a compound microscope

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses, microscopy

In the book 'Materials Characterization: Introduction to Microscopic and Spectroscopic Methods, Second Edition pdf' its says:

> The total magnification of a compound microscope as shown in Figure 1.1 should be the magnification of the objective lens multiplied by that of the projector lens. $$M=M_1M_2\frac{(v_1-f_1)(v_2-f_2)}{f_1f_2}$$ Where: $f$ is the focal length of the lens $v$ is the distance between the image and lens.
> [image: Blockquote]

Is this formula right? Should it not be: $$M=M_1M_2=\frac{(v_1-f_1)(v_2-f_2)}{f_1f_2}$$

I know this is a simple question, i just want to make sure the textbook is not wrong. In the event that the textbook is wrong on such a simple equation, i want learn form a different textbook for harder material.

---

> [image: Blockquote]

Answer (score 0):

The missing = sign in the equation is just a typo in the book,  one occasional typo does not make a book bad. would be nice to write it to the editor of the book.